# Are these two constructions semantically the same or different?

Tags: meaning, gerunds, infinitives

It is very common to use a to-infinitive or gerund clause at the beginning of a sentence as for the following:

1. To drive a motorbike is dangerous.
2. Driving a motorbike is dangerous.

My question is: Are they semantically the same or different?

Answer (score 1):

The latter is fine because a gerund can serve as a subject in an English clause.

The former, however, is a bit awkward and unusual but still technically grammatical. An infinitive clause does not normally function as a subject but it's bound to be '[extraposed](http://www.ucl.ac.uk/internet-grammar/function/extra.htm)'. To do this, you move the infinitive clause to the end of the sentence and use the dummy pronoun "it" to fill the empty slot in the subject position.

i. [To drive a motorbike] is dangerous. 
ii. __is dangerous [to drive a motorbike]. 
iii. **It** is dangerous to drive a motorbike.

Comment: You're right.  Moving the to-infinitive clause to a final position is better, but to-infinitive clause constructions in an initial position are sometimes seen as examples in grammar reference books. So my original question was about the difference in meaning between the to-infinitive and gerund clause constructions.

Answer (score -1):

The sentences are semantically and grammatically different.

Making errors is human.

To make errors is a verb and a complement but not the start of any sentence I can think of. 
I suggest making a sentence that begins with "to make errors " as the subject, and see if it would be any different, the same, or if it even made any sense.

1. Making errors is human.

   ```
     v.
   ```
2. To make  error is human.

Not only the meanings of these two sentences are diverging, but they are also contradictory, in my opinion.

Comment: Infinitives like "to drive" can act as subjects of verbs, so the sentence "to drive a motorbike is dangerous" IS a complete sentence. In (American) standard English, the gerund is commonly used as a subject, while the infinitive is not commonly used. It is unusual to use an infinitive this way, but it is still grammatical. https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/627/03/

Comment: BY + verb + ING

Comment: First, there is no passive form of the sentences "to drive a motorbike is dangerous" OR "driving a motorbike is dangerous" because the verb BE is not a transitive verb. Only verbs that take direct object can be used in the passive voice.

Comment: Second, while it is certainly true that prepositions such as BY can only be followed by the gerund form of a verb, that does not mean that other non-finite forms, such as the to-infinitive, cannot function as noun phrases in other constructions. Just because a construction (such as using the to-infinitive as the subject of a finite verb) is rare does not mean it is ungrammatical.

Comment: To err is human.

Comment: To err is a verb. Making errors makes us human.

Comment: the noun "error" is countable. You can make "an" error, or you can make (several) "errors".

Comment: Could you explain more how #1 differs from #2? Also, the sentence doesn't make sense.

Comment: I also don't see how you conclude that the meanings are different.